# OnCreate called twice (without any sort of configuration change) and app crashes

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-lifecycle, oncreate

Please bear with me here, This is an important Intro... and I have been banging my head into the wall with this for a week now.

I have an android app, and one of the big features in the app was already  implemented in the **old app** by another programmer.  meaning -> the code does work is the **old app**, and I want to use it in the **new version**, but I haven't written it myself, so I am not exactly sure what is going on in there (it **should** work fine, **old app** still works).

**The issue is this:**

In the activity I start using the standard `startActivity`, the `onCreate` is called twice for some weird reason.

Now, it has nothing to do with `onConfigurationChanged` (its not getting called), or any other orientation stuff or something like that.

Another thing is - I tried to put a **breakpoint** in `onCreate` to see that its acctaully called twice, but the code stops at the breakpoint **only at the first** `onCreate`, and after that the breakpoint  isn't caught, **even though** `onCreate` **is definatly called again**.

I check it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
    Log.i("test", "onCreate()  " + ts);
}
```

What happens is that I see in the log **"onCreate() 4444"** for example, and after about 3-4 seconds **the emulator log is cleared**, I see **"onCreate() 4448"**, and the app crashes. So `onCreate` is called twice, even though I can't catch the second time on breakpoint.

The problem is I have some initiation code

```
currentCamera = GlobalInfo.getInstance().getCurrentCamera();
cameraPreviewStreamClint = currentCamera.getpreviewStreamClient(); // Line 2
```

In the **first** time of `onCreate` all works well, but in the **second** time, `currentCamera` gets `null` and so the app crashes in **Line 2** with a **NullPointerException**.

**Now**, I managed to find 4 lines of code, which are in `onResume`, **and when I comment them out**, onCreate is called only **once** and its all good (besides the fact that I obviously need those 4 lines of code to do initiation stuff for the camera). The activity is running but does nothing without those lines.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // this code makes the Activity to recreate! onCreate called twice
    presenter.submitAppInfo();
    presenter.initPreview();
    presenter.initStatus();
    presenter.addEvent();
}
```

Again, this is the part of the code which **wasn't written by me**, so I really dont know what sort of stuff in happening over there.

**MY QUESTION IS -** What kind of work (threads/ui/anything else) can make an `Activity`'s `onCreate` method to be called twice, without an ability to debug it???

In the second time the app crashes because of the **NullPinterException** which is caused because maybe some variable is already "used" in the first `onCreate`..? I really don't know...

Any ideas/thoughts will be welcomed.. I am really at wit's end with this.

**----- EDIT: -----**

**AndroidManifest.xml** looks like this for the activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".cameraFullVersion.View.Activity.PreviewActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

I checked, this line of code `presenter.submitAppInfo();` doesn't cause the issues, so you can ignore it.

When running `onResume` like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // this code makes the Activity to recreate! onCreate called twice
    presenter.submitAppInfo();
    presenter.initPreview();
   // presenter.initStatus();
   // presenter.addEvent();
}
```

Something different happens. the app crashes but without an **excpetion** you can find in the log, the Info log just says:

```
09-30 00:59:19.842 10039-10039/com.ofekagmon.apps.ifloat W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e5db8)
09-30 00:59:22.852 10039-10039/com.ofekagmon.apps.ifloat I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10039 SIG: 9
```

So, with only the first two lines

```
    presenter.submitAppInfo();
    presenter.initPreview();
```

App crashes with **Sending signal. PID: 10039 SIG: 9**.

And when un-commenting this line (3rd line in `onResume`): `presenter.initStatus();`, app crashes and `onCreate` run twice, as described.

The **PreviewPresenter** class is pretty big and ugly.. I'll try to put only what relevant.. sorry for that, not my code:

```
public class PreviewPresenter extends BasePresenter {
    private static final String TAG = "PreviewPresenter";
    private MediaPlayer videoCaptureStartBeep;
    private MediaPlayer modeSwitchBeep;
    private MediaPlayer stillCaptureStartBeep;
    private MediaPlayer continuousCaptureBeep;
    private Activity activity;
    private PreviewView previewView;
    private CameraProperties cameraProperties;
    private CameraAction cameraAction;
    private CameraState cameraState;
    private PreviewStream previewStream;
    private FileOperation fileOperation;
    private ICatchWificamPreview cameraPreviewStreamClint;
    private MyCamera currentCamera;
    private ICatchWificamProperty currentPropertiesClint;
    private ICatchWificamControl currentActionClint;
    private ICatchWificamState currentStateClint;
    private ICatchWificamPlayback currentphotoPlaybackClint;
    private ICatchWificamInfo currentInfoClint;
    private PreviewHandler previewHandler;
    private SDKEvent sdkEvent;
    private int curMode = PreviewMode.APP_STATE_NONE_MODE;
    private Timer videoCaptureButtomChangeTimer;
    public boolean videoCaptureButtomChangeFlag = true;
    private Timer recordingLapseTimeTimer;
    private int lapseTime = 0;
    private List<SettingMenu> settingMenuList;
    private boolean allowClickButtoms = true;
    private int currentSettingMenuMode;
    private int cacheTime;
    private WifiSSReceiver wifiSSReceiver;
    private Boolean supportStreaming = true;
    private long lastCilckTime = 0;
    private long lastRecodeTime;
    private Tristate ret;

    public PreviewPresenter(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // This method is called once from the activity `onCreate`
    public void setView(PreviewView previewView) {
        this.previewView = previewView;
        initCfg(); // Base method from `BasePresenter`
        initData();
    }

    public void initData() {
        cameraProperties = CameraProperties.getInstance();
        cameraAction = CameraAction.getInstance();
        cameraState = CameraState.getInstance();
        previewStream = PreviewStream.getInstance();
        fileOperation = FileOperation.getInstance();
        currentCamera = GlobalInfo.getInstance().getCurrentCamera();
            cameraPreviewStreamClint = currentCamera.getpreviewStreamClient();

        videoCaptureStartBeep = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.camera_timer);
        stillCaptureStartBeep = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.captureshutter);
        continuousCaptureBeep = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.captureburst);
        modeSwitchBeep = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.focusbeep);

        GlobalInfo.getInstance().enableConnectCheck(true);
        previewHandler = new PreviewHandler();
        sdkEvent = new SDKEvent(previewHandler);

        if (cameraProperties.hasFuction(0xD7F0)) {
            cameraProperties.setCaptureDelayMode(1);
        }

        AppLog.i(TAG, "cameraProperties.getMaxZoomRatio() =" + cameraProperties.getMaxZoomRatio());
    }

 public void initPreview() {
        AppLog.i(TAG, "initPreview curMode=" + curMode);
        previewView.setMaxZoomRate(cameraProperties.getMaxZoomRatio());
        previewView.updateZoomViewProgress(cameraProperties.getCurrentZoomRatio());
        if (cameraState.isMovieRecording()) {
            // Code goes into here
            AppLog.i(TAG, "camera is recording...");
            changeCameraMode(PreviewMode.APP_STATE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, ICatchPreviewMode.ICH_VIDEO_PREVIEW_MODE);
            curMode = PreviewMode.APP_STATE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
            startVideoCaptureButtomChangeTimer();
            //start recording time timer
               startRecordingLapseTimeTimer(cameraProperties.getVideoRecordingTime());

        } 
        //do not start preview,
    }

    public void initStatus() {
        int resid = ThumbnailOperation.getBatteryLevelIcon();
        if (resid > 0) {
            previewView.setBatteryIcon(resid);
            if (resid == R.mipmap.ifloat_icon) {
                AppDialog.showLowBatteryWarning(activity);
            }
        }
        IntentFilter wifiSSFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION);
        wifiSSReceiver = new WifiSSReceiver();
        activity.registerReceiver(wifiSSReceiver, wifiSSFilter);
    }
}
```

See this method `initStatus()`.
When I debug, and on this method, and doing **step over**, it steps into the `ActivityThread.java` class and throw the **null exception**. The line which it happens in is changing.

There are still methods here like:

```
changeCameraMode(), startVideoCaptureButtomChangeTimer() and startRecordingLapseTimeTimer()
```

Its just too much to write down.

I'll start with this and hopefully you guys can help me.

**Again**, the problems lines are:

`initStatus()` in one of the lines-> **Null exception**.

And `initPreview();` causes **App crashes with **Sending signal. PID: 10039 SIG: 9**.

Comment: Can you post the presenter class code?

Comment: and post the Activities entry in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: the four methods in `onResume()`, we need to see those to actually see what, if anything, is calling this activity more than once

Comment: thank you for your answers. I updated my question, hopefully with enough to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Ofek Agmon I got the exact issue in this post , please share the solution in the comment or via answer.